# Can't use react-native-snap-carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

I would like use react-native-snap-carousel but when I try to init in I have an error :(

the exemple :

```
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

export class MyCarousel extends Component {

_renderItem ({item, index}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.slide}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

render () {
    return (
        <Carousel
          ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
          data={this.state.entries}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
          itemWidth={itemWidth}
        />
    );
}}
```

My code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 _renderItem ({item, index}) {
   return (
      <View style={styles.slide}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
      </View>
);}
 render () {
   return (
    <Carousel
      ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
      data={this.state.entries}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      sliderWidth={150}
      itemWidth={100}
    />
); 
}} 
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
   }});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JobSr.png)
the same on app.js react Native

I'have see a issue (the same like me)
[link to Github Issue](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/205)

But not answer and issue be close

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the screenshot says, `this.state.entries` is `null`.

You must initialize it :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      entries: [],
    }
  }
  _renderItem ({item, index}) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.slide}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
      </View>
  );}

  render () {
    return (
      <Carousel
        ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
        data={this.state.entries}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        sliderWidth={150}
        itemWidth={100}
      />
 ); 
}}
```

In this example, `entries: []` wont display anything since there's no object in it. You can initialize it with wanted data:

```
entries: [
  { title: 'hello' },
  { title: 'world' },
]
```

Btw, this issue has nothing to do with the plugin itself, even if they could catch it.

Comment: Thank a lot @poptocrack :)